# split out file name from path in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field that contains windows file paths, like so:

```
\\fs1\foo\bar\snafu.txt
c:\this\is\why\i\drink\snafu.txt
\\fs2\bippity\baz.zip
\\fs3\boppity\boo\baz.zip
c:\users\chris\donut.c
```

What I need to do is find then number of duplicated files names (regardless of what directory they are in).  So I want to find "snafu.txt" and "baz.zip", but not donut.c.

Is there a way in PostgreSQL (8.4) to find the last part of a file path?  If I can do that, then I can use count/group to find my problem children.

Answer (score 16):

You can easily strip the path up to the last directory separator with an expression like

```sql
regexp_replace(path, '^.+[/\\]', '')
```

This will match the ocassional forward slashes produced by some software as well.  Then you just count the remaining file names like

```sql
WITH files AS (
    SELECT regexp_replace(my_path, '^.+[/\\]', '') AS filename
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT filename, count(*) AS count
FROM files
GROUP BY filename
HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: I'm not very good in regexp, but shouldn't the `'$.+[/\\]'` in your first snippet be `'^.+[/\\]'`, like in the second one?

Comment: @AndriyM thank you very much, I corrected it only the whole query and forgot about the other one.  Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace(path_field, '.+/', '') from files_table;
```

Comment: This works perfectly for paths based using '/' delimiter.  But the original question was about windows file paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION basename(text) RETURNS text
    AS $basename$
declare
    FILE_PATH alias for $1;
    ret         text;
begin
    ret := regexp_replace(FILE_PATH,'^.+[/\\]', '');
    return ret;
end;
$basename$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```