# PostgreSQL Substring extraction

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have a column called 'uri' which has values as follows:

```
file://c:\file1.txt
file://\\1.1.1.1\folder1\folder1a\file2.txt
file://d:\sub1\sub2\sub3\file3.txt
```

I'm trying to remove the filename from the uri to leave

```
file://c:\
file://\\1.1.1.1\folder1\folder1a\
file://d:\sub1\sub2\sub3\
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750846/split-out-file-name-from-path-in-postgres. regexp_replace(your_column_name, '^.+[/\\]', '')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
with t (col) as (
    select 'file://c:\file1.txt' union all
    select 'file://\\1.1.1.1\folder1\folder1a\file2.txt' union all
    select 'file://d:\sub1\sub2\sub3\file3.txt'
)
select regexp_replace(col, '(^.*?)[^\\]*$', '\1') as output from t;
```

Produces:

```
output
---------------------------------
file://c:\
file://\\1.1.1.1\folder1\folder1a\
file://d:\sub1\sub2\sub3\
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/IFC77070)